# Why `Phalcon` store a special key `_PHCM` to hold all keys?

Tags: php, phalcon

I just curious why do this. Just for implement method `queryKeys`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked somewhere. Have you tried researching at all? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I searched stackoverflow for the keywords `phalcon phcm`, I got nothing. Any other keywords to recommend?